# How to integrate $\int \frac{\sqrt{ax+b}}{x}\,dx$

Tags: calculus

Calculus question:
How to integrate $$\int \frac{\sqrt{ax+b}}{x}\,dx $$
I have tried doing substitution as $u=ax+b$; but the answer I get is not correct.

Comment: Try doing the substitution $u=\frac{\sqrt{ax+b}}{x}$

Comment: Actually, make the substitution $\theta=\arctan(\frac{\sqrt{ax}}{\sqrt{b}})$

Comment: That second substitution actually leads you to the problem of integrating the reciprocal of $\sin(\theta) \cos^2(\theta)$

Comment: Show us what happened when you used $u=ax+b$, and how you know it's not the correct answer. Then, we can probably help.

Answer (score 2):

The substitution you suggested would work?

If put $u = \sqrt{ax + b}$ then $ax + b = u^2$ and $ a dx = 2u du$. The integral becomes

$\int \frac{\sqrt{ax +b}}{x} dx = a \int \frac{u}{u^2-b} 2u du$
which can be written as
$2 a \int \frac{u^2}{u^2-b} du$. Then write

$\frac{1}{u^2-b} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{b}}(\frac{1}{u-\sqrt{b}} - \frac{1}{u+\sqrt{b}})$ and then need to calculate integrals of the form $\int \frac{u^2}{u + \alpha} du$.

Comment: You do polynomial division first, before the partial-fraction decomposition: $\frac{u^2}{u^2-b}=1+\frac{b}{u^2-b}$.